# What is the difference between GitHub Flow and GitLab Flow?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

Recently I've found three concepts of a workflow in Git:

- GitFlow
- GitHub Flow
- GitLab Flow

I've read [the nice articles](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html) about it but I don't understand GitLab Flow very well.

Briefly.

**GitFlow**

[image: gitflow]

We've a master branch as a production branch. Also we have a develop branch where every developer merges his features. Sometimes we create a release branch to deploy our features in production. If we have a bug in the release branch, fix it and pull changes into the develop branch. If we have a critical bug in production, create new hotfix-branch, fix the bug and merge branch with production (master) and develop branches.

This approach works well if we seldom publish results of our work. (Maybe once every 2 weeks).

**GitHub Flow**

[image: github flow]

We have a master branch as a production branch. And we (as developers) can  create branches for adding new features or fixing bugs and merge them with production (master) branch. It sounds very simple. This approach fits for extreme programming where the production branch is deployed several times in a day.

**GitLab Flow**

[image: gitlab flow production]

[image: gitlab flow environment]

[image: gitlab flow release]

I've seen new terms like a pre-production, a production, a release (stable) branch and a staging environment, a pre-production environment, a production environment. What relationships do they have between them?

I understand it this way: If we need to add a new feature we deploy a pre-production branch from the master branch. When we have finished the feature, we deploy a production branch from the pre-production branch. A pre-production branch is the intermediate stage. And then the master branch pulls all changes from the production branch.

The approach is good if we want to see each separate feature; we just checkout in the branch what we need to look at.

But if we need to show our work we create a release branch with a tag as late as possible. If later we fix bugs in the master branch we need to cherry-pick them to the last release branch. At the end we have the release branch with tags that can help us to move between versions.

Is my understanding correct?

What is the difference between `pull` and `cherry-pick`?

Comment: There is a good "GitLab Flow in practice" documentation: https://github.com/jadsonjs/gitlab-flow

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**GitLab Flow** proposes to use `master` and `feature` branches too. Once  feature is done we merge it back to `master` branch. This part looks the same as in **GitHub Flow**.

Then my understanding is that they give us 2 options on how to do it depending on whether it's SAAS app or mobile app (which can be release out to the world).

If this is SAAS app we use environment branches e.g. `pre-production` and `production`. These branches are created off the `master` when we are ready to deploy our application. Having different branches per environment allow us to setup CI/CD tool to automatically deploy on commits made to these branches. If there is a critical issue we fix it in `feature` or `master` branch and then merge it to `environment` branches.

As for applications which can be released out to the world (e.g. mobile or desktop apps) my understanding is that they propose to use different model by using `release` branches instead of environment branches. We still do all work in `feature` branches and merge them back to `master` branch upon completion. Then when we make sure that `master` branch is stable enough i.e. we have already performed all testing and bug-fixing we create `release` branch and release our software. If there is a critical issue we first fix it in `master` branch and cherry-pick a fix to `release` branch.

Comment: I think Environment branches are suitable for SaaS that need deploy to an environment. Release branches are suitable for software that is a software simply, it don't need deploy, user will do that. If i have a release, beside, i want provide this release as a service, can i use both versions?

Answer (score 52):

It has been a year now since this post was raised, but considering future readers and the fact things have changed a bit I think it's worth refreshing.

**GitHub Flow** as [originally depicted by Scott Chacon in 2011](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) assumed each change once reviewed on a `feature branch` and merged into `master` should be deployed to production immediately. While this worked at the time and conformed to the only GitHub Flow rule, which is *anything in the master branch is deployable*, [it was quickly discovered](https://github.com/blog/1241-deploying-at-github) that in order to keep `master` a true record of known **working production code** the actual deployment to production should happen from the `feature branch` **before** merging it into `master`. Deploying from the `feature branch` makes perfect sense as in the case of any issue production can be instantaneously reverted by deploying `master` to it. Please take a look at [a short visual introduction](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) to GitHub Flow.

**GitLab Flow** is kind of an extension to GitHub Flow accompanied by a set of [guidelines and best practices](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html) that aim to further standardize the process. Aside from promoting ready to deploy `master` branch and feature branches (same as GitHub Flow) it introduces three other kinds of branches:

1. [`Production` branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#production-branch-with-gitlab-flow)
2. [Environment branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#environment-branches-with-gitlab-flow): `uat`, `pre-production`, `production`
3. [Release branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#release-branches-with-gitlab-flow): `1-5-stable`, `1-6-stable`

I believe above names and examples are self-descriptive, thus I won't elaborate further.